# OnCollisionEnter2D выдает ошибку Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект у которого есть `Rigidbody2D` и `Box Collider2D` на нем висит этот скрипт:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
    {
        GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>().enabled = true;
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<FixedJoint2D>().connectedBody = collision.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
```

выдает такую ошибку:

> error CS1061: 'Collision2D' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetComponent' and no accessible extension method 'GetComponent'
> accepting a first argument of type 'Collision2D' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что правильно так:

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent...
          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

ибо у объекта типа **[Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html)** нет никаких `GetComponent`, только у `GameObject`